# Как прибавить значение к полю, исходя из текущего значения MongoDB

Tags: node.js, база-данных, mongodb, mongoose

хотел бы узнать, как можно добавить значение к полю, исходя из текущего значения поля документа.

Пример, есть документы с полями `{name: String, price: Number}`

Нужно прибавить во всех документах **20% от price**. Допустим, документ `{name: "Яблоко", price: 100}`, должен стать `{name: "Яблоко", price: 120}`, а `{name: "Банан", price: 70}`, должен стать `{name: "Банан", price: 84}`.

Есть оператор **$inc**, но он добавляет конкретное значение, например 45, но мне нужно добавить price * 0.2, то есть 20% от значения price. Как это можно сделать?

Спасибо за Ваш ответ!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого есть оператор $mul. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/mul/